# Cannot understand Python telegram bot Job queue

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

It's probably my fault, but I can't make the "run_repeating" method works. I took a look at the examples from the official Github repo and find that [timerbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/timerbot.py). I tried to follow the same idea in my code, but I failed. I mean, the timerbot works, but I'm doing something wrong I can't figure out that is not working in my code. And I know, timerbot uses "run_once" instead of "run_repeating" but the documentation indicates a [pretty similar syntax for both](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html?highlight=run_repeating#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating).

By the way, my bot is supposed to be a price tracker for Amazon products using Selenium (that part is ok). The bot get the url, then tracks the product until the price get cheaper and notify the user with a message.

This is basically the code (the part that matters):

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler
from selenium import webdriver, common
import time, re

#Variables
token = open('note_token_telegram', 'r').read()
driver_path = open('note_driver','r').read()
bin_path = open('note_bin','r').read()
  
#Track
def track(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    data = context.user_data
    url = context.args[0]
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id 
    if re.match(r'(https:\/\/www\.amazon\.).*', url):
        print('track running')
        #Scrape 
        driver_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        driver_options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver_options.binary_location = bin_path.strip()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path.strip(), options=driver_options)
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            try:
                price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_ourprice')
            except common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                try:
                    price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_saleprice')
                except:
                    price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_dealprice')
            name =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#productTitle')
        except:
            update.message.reply_text('Are you sure this is an Amazon product page? '+url)
            driver.close()
        data[name.text] = {'url': url, 'price' : price.text}
        print(data.items())
        driver.close()
        print(chat_id)
        context.job_queue.run_repeating(notification, 30, context=chat_id, name=str(chat_id))
        update.message.reply_text("Good! We are now tracking one more Product!")
def notification(update, context):
#The Script
    job = context.job
    print('notification running')
    print(type(job.context))
    print(job.context)
    print(context.user_data.items())
    #Scrape 
    driver_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    driver_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver_options.binary_location = bin_path.strip()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path.strip(), options=driver_options)
    for i in context.user_data.items():
        driver.get(i[1]['url'])
        try:
            try:
                new_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_ourprice')
            except common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                try:
                    new_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_saleprice')
                except:
                    new_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_dealprice')
        except:
            context.bot.send_message(job.context, text='Are you sure this is an Amazon product page?'+i['url'])
                        
            #Notification
                        
            if '-' in new_price.text and float(new_price.text[1:4]) < float(i[1]['price']):
                context.bot.send_message(job.context, text=f"It's on your budget! \n{i[0]} \n {price.text} \n {i[1]['url']}")
                driver.close()
            elif float(new_price.text[1:9]) < float(i[1]['price']):
                context.bot.send_message(job.context, text=f"It's on your budget! \n{i[0]} \n {price.text} \n {i[1]['url']}")
                driver.close()
            else:
                driver.close()

#Main Function
def main():
    updater = Updater(token.strip())
    #Commands Instantiation
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('track', track))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, help))
   

    #Main loop methods
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the error message I am receiveing:

```
raise ValueError('The following arguments have not been supplied: %s' %
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: context
```

It's indicating a value error, but I have paste the context and all that stuff in the right place at the notification function, don't I? I just follow the same principles of timerbot.py (at least I tried...).

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra input argument for your notification function:

```
def notification(update, context):
```

should be:

```
def notification(context):
```

Another thing to keep in mind, you don't currently have a way to remove jobs, so any product you want to check will continue infinitely until you restart your bot. You can add a "last" parameter to your `run_repeating()`, or add a command that will let you remove jobs (you should give them more unique names if this is the way you want to handle it).

**UPDATE:**

To pass data to the repeating job, try this:

```py
def track(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    data = context.user_data
    ...
    data["url"] = url
    data["price"] = price.text
    data["chat_id"] = update.message.chat_id
    ...
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(notification, 3, context=context.user_data, name=str(chat_id))


def notification(context):
    job = context.job
    chat_id = job.context["chat_id"]
    url = job.context["url"]
    price = job.context["price"]
    ...
```

As far as naming jobs for removal, product names sounds good, or even the product id which is guaranteed to be unique (I think...).

Comment: Thanks! It works! And yes I need a solution to remove the jobs. I was planning to use the products names... Would be perfect if I could to set IDs (like in SQL). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Now it's raising other error:
File "bot.py", line 103, in notification
    print(context.user_data.items())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
It means, context.user_data is not being read as a dictionary, as it should be. I run a type command in it and shows "NoneType".

Comment: I think I have a solution

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my work! 
About the removing issue, I named the jobs as the message IDs instead of the chat IDs, what is even more unique, so the user can add more jobs (it means, track more products at the same time). I still need to work on that but I think I'm in a good direction. 
Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind message ids will change with every new message, so it might be hard to keep track of them